# I am trying to save a serialized cts:query with placeholder values into a document and it keeps throwing an XDMP-REVIDXBADQRY error

Tags: marklogic

I found the document will save, if I remove my placeholder elements.  Also found if I turn off "**fast reverse searches**" index then it saves. I want to be able to quickly replace any placeholder values and then pass it into `cts:query()`. Is there a way to keep that index on and keep my placeholder elements?

Answer (score 1):

You could express your template with placeholder elements, but with the whole thing in a different namespace, and then use XSL to translate to the cts namespace once you've filled things in.

Comment: Instead of XSLT to change the namespace, you could also use http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_change-element-ns-deep.html, a function that is available with `import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com" at "/MarkLogic/functx/functx-1.0-doc-2007-01.xqy";`